# Netbeans design view?

Tags: netbeans, view

How do I go about using the design view in Netbeans to use with the Palette for web development?

I try going to View > Editors > Source/Design but Editors is grayed out and I cannot access it.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans no longer has a design view for web development (latest 6.9, and 7 versions, maybe since 6.5 but I don't remember). There was a mention somewhere about it for the future but it's not in the roadmap.