# Netbeans - Design view not available

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I'm following a tutorial on using SOAP web services and for this i must edit my file WelcomeSOAP.java using design view, however design view is not available, only the 'source' and 'history' views are on the bar to the top; also if i go to view > editors they are the only two options. I have come across this question:

[Netbeans design view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971192/netbeans-design-view)

However, both my laptop and computer are running netbeans 7.4 and the design view is available on my desktop, but I need to be able to use it on my laptop too. Does anyone know how to enable design view?

EDIT:

I have tried deactivating and reactivating the GUI plugin, and also re-installed netbeans, both of which did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Java Application, then right click on "Source Packages" - "New" - "Other" - (Categories) "Swing GUI Form" - (File Type) "JApplet Form"

Job Done.......

(I tried thin with 8.0.2)

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Plugins->Available plugins, search for 'GUI' if you need Then check: Spring framework for Java SE. It works for me on NetBeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

In the Menu Bar Go to - 
View > (Check) Show Editor Toolbar
Done.

Answer (score 1):

Alright i've found the answer. When you are in your source package, right click and there should be options for "forms"

Comment: so that means what i'm saying is you copy all of your code, delete that source file, make the form and paste it there

Answer (score 1):

search for 'web service' and make sure that 'Java Web and EE' is **active**

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. It might be because you're not using the latest version of NetBeans (I had the same issue). Get NetBeans 8.0.2 and reinstall the GUI plugin. it should work then.

Comment: When I re-installed netbeans, i updated to the latest version, I have the GUI plugin but design view is still not available

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the plugin named web services. You can find it in this path and search for it there in the search box in top right corner.

> tools->plugins->available plugins

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Plugins->Available plugins, search for 'web service' if you need
Then check:
RESTFUL Web Service, 
SOAP Web Service.
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

> Error : "Design view cannot be rendered."

**Below procedure worked for me:**

- Close the file that has the design view (Web Services folder -> YourService)
- Close the netbeans
- Open Netbeans
- Open the file again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not deleted the ".Form" file (Thats's what I did while rearranging everything). It is the file that lets you edit the form in netbeans. I couldn't find how to recover.